# Defined values in SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, defined

Just wondering what peoples opinions are about defining values inside SQL statements when using the prepared statements such as:

```
$sql->query("SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_NAME." WHERE id = :id");
$sql->bind(':id', $id);
```

Not all the code but you can see what I am getting at. Should I bind the table name is what I am basically asking.

Comment: Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/182353/1438393) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use prepared statements for table and column names.
I advise you to use prepared statements everywhere since it is resilient against SQL injection (you don't have to care about escaping your values).
They also provide a performance benefits if you run them more than once.